# Add class "item_active" to parent LI when a child LI has "item_active"

Tags: javascript, jquery

It should be easy, but somehow I didn't get this one yet. Hope you can help me.

Simply: I would like the parent LI to get a class "item_active" added when one of the child LIs have that class too.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class=""><a href="main"><span>Main</span></a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="services" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Services</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="first"><span>First</span></a></li>
      <li class="item_active"><a href="second"><span>Second</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="third"><span>Third</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about"><span>About</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

You'll see that the second LI in the sub dropdown menu has the class "item_active".

In this scenario I want jQuery to add the class "item-active" to the LI with the class "dropdown" in my case.

I tried many different things. This is may be most close, yet it did nothing:

```
$('.navbar-nav li ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('item_active')) {
        $(this).closest('.dropdown').addClass('item_active');
    } 
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Preben/cxnx1147/2/)

I have read many different answers in SO, but not one that solved this.

Comment: It looks to me as though it should be working. Have you validated that it actually isn't getting the class by inspecting the element, and have you validated via console.log()'ing that the code is actually being run? Is this code running from inside a $(document).ready() function?

Comment: you forgot to include jQuery library. Fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/cxnx1147/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddle you provided doesn't use jQuery. Load that in and it would work.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/cxnx1147/6/

Also, keep in mind that bootstrap uses particular classes that override properties. Just because you can't "see" the class, doesn't mean it hasn't been added to the element.

To illustrate this, I used the following:

```
.item_active {
  background: yellow!important;
}
```

It's important to note that `!important` is not considered good practice though.
Hope this helps.

Comment: That was very both a bit embarrassing and strange. I included it, but it must have  forgotten to store it. :-)

Comment: I always use Inspector in Chrome to verify that a class has been added or not. Thank you for the comment :-)